# restful web development in scala

Tags: scala, rest

I ve been a php developer for the past 4 years and worked in OO PHP and almost all sorts of PHP mvc frameworks. Ive joined a new company now and here we use scala for web development. We have a product which has a frontend developed in a js mvc and a backend in scala. Actually this kind of restful architecture itself is brand new for me. In PHP we just use PHP for both frontend and backend. So i started working in scala and did some basic console app stuff. But there are no articles on how i must use scala to do restful web development. There is a framework called lift developed in scala. But we havent used that. Ours is a pure scala app without lift stuff. I found out two blogs but it has too little information on implementation.

So can any one point me in the right direction on when to use the restful architecure as against mvc architecture and absolute newbie guides to creating a web app using restful architecture in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the libraries and tools mentioned [here](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries). There are some specifically targeted at REST.

As for Lift itself, if you are going to use that, then the Lift mailing list is your best resource. Also, Manning's [Lift in Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/) by Tim Perrett is a very good book.